# how could jenkins "pipeline stage" hit all NODE agents with the same "LABLES" name?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

As we have already setup the nodes on "Dashboard/Nodes" with the same "Labels" for both 2 nodes:

- 192.168.1.240    Labels: blog-vue
- 192.168.1.241    Labels: blog-vue

the Pipeline scripts is as below:

```
pipeline {
agent {label 'blog-vue'}
stages {
    stage("Get hostname") {  
        steps {
            sh "hostname"
        }
    }
}
```

}

but, if we click "build" button to run the script, the scripts will ONLY be executed on the first server listed on the node configurations. is here anbody know why? or how could jenkins pipeline "stage" hit all agent nodes with the same "LABLES" name?  rather than to write the "agent labels info" in diffrent "stage block" with different "labels names".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark, but we had something similar happen when folks copy-pasted the label from one system to another and accidentally grabbed some whitespace at the beginning or end. Try removing everything in the label and manually typing it / selecting it from the dropdown if it appears.

I also see a related issue posted on stackexchange [load balancing jenkins](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/6827/load-balancing-of-jenkins-nodes-without-load-balancing-plugin)

We also use Least Load plug-in like that issue's answer. I would look into it if the label issue isn't of concern.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i've tried many times for the words correction check. but seems this function does not work for pipeline-style projects, free style project supports.

Comment: I updated it to mention we use the Least Load plug-in to get this functionality in my current job. We use it HEAVILY for pipeline jobs, so I'd give it a try.

Comment: If this answered your question or you got anything from it, please mark it as the answer/approved.